# data loss when using ajax loader image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem with ajax loader image when I use the `load()` function, the following javascript code works fine:

```
$('#myscroll').load('data.php','total='+totalItems+'&id='+ID+'&worker=$worker&sets=$sets', function(newi){
    updatestatus();
});
```

In the data.php, it receives the `$_GET` variables `total`, `id`, `worker` and `sets`.

However if I do:

```
var ajax_load = \"<img src='myajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />\";

$('#myscroll').html(ajax_load).load('data.php','total='+totalItems+'&id='+ID+'&worker=$worker&sets=$sets', function(newi) {
    updatestatus();
});
```

In the data.php, it doesn't receive the the `$_GET` variables `total`, `id`, `worker` and `sets`. How can I still make it work when I use the ajax loader, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make ajax_load a legal javascript string, change this:

```
var ajax_load = \"<img src='myajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />\";
```

to this:

```
var ajax_load = "<img src='myajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
```

A javascript error like this will keep the rest of the code that follows it from executing.

I'd also strongly suggest you learn how to look for javascript errors in the error console or the debug console since that will save you countless hours when there's some sort of javascript error that keeps your code from executing properly.